# Why can't I get a random file from the directory?

Tags: python, random, ms-word, docx

I'm trying to get a random word file from a specified directory, but it returns nothing Here's the some part of the code.

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*docx')):
    fl = []
    fl.append(filename)
return fl

choice = random.choice(fl)
doc = docx.Document(choice)
print(doc.paragraphs[0].text) # There is a paragraph on the document starting on the first line so problem is not there.
```

There is nothing wrong with the path. Eveything was working just fine when I was not trying to get only one random file instead of all the files.

1. What am I doing it wrong?
2. Is there any more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop logic you are initializing the `fl` list every time you are getting the `filename` which makes the `fl` value to include only last filename(which makes random.choice function give you only same filename), instead rewrite it as,

```
fl = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*docx')):
    fl = fl.append(filename)
```

though the looping is not needed in your case, I suggest you look at what @kra3 answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48575197/3872951).

Answer (score 2):

`return fl` is looking kind of odd.
Otherwise it should work.

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*docx')
choice = random.choice(files) # each time you get a random file out of files.
```

You don't have to create another list running files through a loop, like you have done.